# is there a work around for javascript echarts symbolRotate which only accepts one number

Tags: javascript, scatter-plot, echarts

I want to display wind direction using the arrow symbol in  E-Chart scatter plot. I have a time-series of wind speeds and directions (0 to 360 degrees) which I need to plot using the 'arrow' as symbol.

reading the documentation of Echart, symbolRotate only accepts a number and not a function.  They allow function for symbolSize but not symbolRotate.

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that you can have customized data items this is done by making each data point a dictionary which includes values and attributes for each point.  See link below for more information:

https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#series-line.data